# How to setup a linux C++ project in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I have an existing C++ project on a linux environment, and would like to import it into the Eclipse IDE.

Not sure if I should start a new Eclipse C++ project, or if there was some way to import the source files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new Eclipse C++ project "in-place", i.e. if you have your sources checked out at /home/joe/mysources, you can select that directory in the new project wizard (uncheck the "use default location" checkbox first). All your source files will show up in the Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

one solution: just create a new C++ projet (Standard make project), checkout/copy your files in it, then right clic on the directory of the project in the ressource view and choose New > Other > C++ > Convert to C/C++ Make project.